# Akka.Net - how to properly analyse occasionally and remedy some rogue messages taking too long to be acted upon

Tags: c#, akka.net

We have code sending 2 duplicate tell messages  ( a integer differences) one after directly the other no processing in between. These normally processed in a few milli seconds, but we are hitting times when one is process instantly the next some 11 seconds later. Which is a life time.

The randomness and sporadic nature of this issue is making it difficult to diagnosis and the fact 99% these message are processed blistering quick makes it a head scratching issue.

Back ground: We have a very controlled /stable  environment 64 bit windows 10  machine.  A dedicated windows server running self hosted webapi using c#, akka services v.1.3 (.net Framework). No akka remoting or clustering. As messages are posted in, actors and child actors  breaking them down process into to smaller and smaller actors, some are stateful basically caching db details about requests to save on DB road trips, as the prices behind requests are fluctuating all the time we look to only post to the DB. None of these parent actors are misbehaving.

Currently logging on entry and exit to processmessage methods provides the only real diagnostics to track behaviour.

It is the behaviour of the message queuing that we think is the issue.

Basically two tells to the same actor, these are  very small messages (less 1k)  to a very small actor whose sole job is just to send http message. The actor has nocaching or Db requests or IO ( other than logging). Once  the message hits the handler's ProcessMessage it is processed in a milli second or 2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your issue correctly, upon receiving a message, it is forwarded to a downstream actor whose job is to call an external server? If that is the case, then Akka.NET is not at fault, why?:

1. Actors process message sequentially and won't process the next message
   unless the current message has been processed completely. The more time it
   takes to handle the current message the more time it takes for the next
   message to be handled.
2. Probably the external server is over loaded and not sending response quickly
   or maybe there is rate limiting turned on at the external server's side.
3. Probably the `httpclient` used by you needs fine-tuning!

If you can post a sample of your code, it will help in understanding your issue better!